# Explanations about the Ifstream get() method behaviour when reading UTF-8 encoded text (C++)

Tags: c++, utf-8, ifstream

I am currently learning how to work with UTF-XX encoded files and text.

I have this simple example:

```
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("data/text.txt");
do {
    char c;
    ifs.get(c);
    printf("%x\n", c);
} while (!ifs.eof());
```

Where the file `text.txt` contains the following strings:

```
yabloko
яблоко
```

The results looks like this:

```
79
61
62
6c
6f
6b
6f
a
ffffffd1
ffffff8f
ffffffd0
ffffffb1
ffffffd0
ffffffbb
ffffffd0
ffffffbe
ffffffd0
ffffffba
ffffffd0
ffffffbe
```

I do understand why I have twice the number of lines for the cyrillic word (because it's UTF-8 encoded and that each character in this case is using 2 bytes), my questions is about what `get()` and `printf()` are doing. More precisely why is my character c printed out as a int? with the first 3 bytes set to FFF? When I look at the doc for the `get()` method I see:

```
int get();
istream& get (char& c);
```

I tried both option. I see the first one returns an int. The second takes a char? I am really confused? Why would these functions extracts anything else from a file than just a single byte (char) at a time and why is the value for the cyrillic characters printed out as for example `ffffffd1` instead of `d1`?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but your `do/while` loop is not validating `get()` succeeds before calling `printf()`, so `c` will be garbage when EOF is reached. You should use a `while` loop instead: `char c; while (ifs.get(c)) { printf("%hhx\n", c); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> More precisely why is my character `c` printed out as a `int`?

[Because `char` is promoted to `int` when passed to `...` argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) of `printf`. On your platform `char` is signed, hence all codes above 127 get promoted to a negative `int`.

You may like to use `%hhx` format specifier to print `char`.

---

[`int istream::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) returns an `int` rather than `char` to be able to distinguish the read character from `EOF`. `Traits::eof()` is normally `int(-1)`. No Unicode character has this code.

Comment: Nice, thank you I am tempted to accept your answer) but do you ask know why the `get()` method returns an int rather than a char?

Comment: @user18490 Added a note about `int get()` for you.

Comment: Makes sense) Thx a lot -